# How will this hard drive setup impact system performance?

Tags: hard-drive, performance

Since most operating systems running on a hard drive get faster with each hard drive memory free, I have got a scenario where if I have two hard drives and then the primary hard drive has only the operating system and the other space is free, and a secondary hard drive that accepts program installations and file storage, how will a system setup this way perform against a system that uses a single hard drive and has been partitioned and has the OS installed on either of the partitions?

Comment: Probably not that different in real-world applications, tbh. *If* you would be bottlenecked on one drive, that's probably because you're loading a lot of data at once *from one location*, for example when installing a program, and that *anyways* would take place on one drive in your proposed system.

Comment: But the hard drive with the OS is free and spends little time addressing, just writing to  and reading the secondary drive is all that is needed?

Comment: Yes, but the OS isn't doing much access from storage once it's booted

Comment: Okay, using SSD as a single unit would be faster than the initial setup?

Comment: Most likely yes.

Comment: using a single disk, there is no conceivable improvement in performance. I generally question your major premise that a less full disk performs better, let alone a less full partition. you are still bottlenecked by the same things: a single disk, on a single controller.

Comment: @FrankThomas, I noticed that my OS is very slow when the hard drive is full and speedy when its got chunks of free memory, is this observation suggesting something?, You know the observation is valid and common

Comment: @TechGeek are you using an SSD? Plus, you're talking about *storage*, not *memory*

Comment: a very full disk will slow you down a lot, but a 90% full disk shouldn't perform much if any worse than a 50% full one. if you are running linux, then go right ahead and do it if it makes sense to you. on windows through, you will have persistent difficulties moving the default program install directories. a lot of things just won't work right, and you will constantly fighting with default behavior

Comment: @Esther, my OS is installed on a hard drive, I just couldn't help but notice system responsiveness when the free space on the HDD is more than 135 Gigs, os boots faster, programs launch faster, no whirring sounds but when is less than 100 all the above become opposites so I thought what if I make this hard drive to have OS only and a secondary one to store files?

Comment: Your first statement does not make sense except for an sshd (which was a short-luved innovation combing an ssd and hdd). Are youvsure both your disks are hard drives?  What you are describing is a variant of a common configuration where the IS is on a small ssd and the data is on a hard drive (but nirmallt programs ate on the ssd as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not that different in real-world applications, tbh. Once the OS has fully booted, it doesn't do that much reading and writing from the hard drive, and definitely not enough that the volume of reads/writes is the bottleneck. *If* you would be bottlenecked on one drive, that's probably because you're loading a lot of data at once *from one location*, for example when installing a program, and that *anyways* would take place on one drive in your proposed system.

This is all assuming you're using "hard drives" (HDDs), as described in the question. If these were SSDs, the situation would be different. SSDs can get *much* slower once they are more than about 75% full, because most SSDs these days store multiple pieces of data per cell, and they have to "move" the data "on top" of whatever you're accessing in order to get to the data underneath. Therefore, keeping SSDs below 75% use most likely *will* speed up the system. If one SSD would otherwise be full, then using 2 can make your system faster.